# What is the cost of creating actors in Akka?

Tags: performance, scala, akka

Consider a scenario in which I am implementing a system that processes incoming tasks using Akka. I have a primary actor that receives tasks and dispatches them to some worker actors that process the tasks.

My first instinct is to implement this by having the dispatcher create an actor for each incoming task. After the worker actor processes the task it is stopped.

This seems to be the cleanest solution for me since it adheres to the principle of "one task, one actor". The other solution would be to reuse actors - but this involves the extra-complexity of cleanup and some pool management.

I know that actors in Akka are cheap. But I am wondering if there is an inherent cost associated with repeated creation and deletion of actors. Is there any hidden cost associated with the data structures Akka uses for the bookkeeping of actors ?

The load should be of the order of tens or hundreds of tasks per second - think of it as a production webserver that creates one actor per request.

Of course, the right answer lies in the profiling and fine tuning of the system based on the type of the incoming load.
But I wondered if anyone could tell me something from their own experience ?

**LATER EDIT:**

I should given more details about the task at hand:

- Only N active tasks can run at some point. As @drexin pointed out - this would be easily solvable using routers. However, the execution of tasks isn't a simple run and be done type of thing.
- Tasks may require information from other actors or services and thus may have to wait and become asleep. By doing so they release an execution slot. The slot can be taken by another waiting actor which now has the opportunity to run. You could make an analogy with the way processes are scheduled on one CPU.
- Each worker actor needs to keep some state regarding the execution of the task.

***Note:*** I appreciate alternative solutions to my problem, and I will certainly take them into consideration. However, I would also like an answer to the main question regarding the intensive creation and deletion of actors in Akka.

Comment: Did you use any of suggested solutions? We have the exact same problem...

Comment: hi!! did you find an answer? how did you solve the problem?

Comment: My understanding is that actors are relatively cheap to create. You should first try to design an actor system that allows you to write the simplest & most understandable code. If this means incapsulating some temporary task with its own local state in a short-lived actor - do it. Then measure and if performance isn't good enough try to tweak the system and reduce the number of actor creations, with the possible downside that actor logic becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 22):

You should not create an actor for every request, you should rather use a router to dispatch the messages to a dynamic amount of actors. That's what routers are for. Read this part of the docs for more information: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4/scala/routing.html

edit:

Creating top-level actors (`system.actorOf`) is expensive, because every top-level actor will initialize an error kernel as well and those are expensive. Creating child actors (inside an actor `context.actorOf`) is way cheaper.

But still I suggest you to rethink this, because depending on the frequency of the creation and deletion of actors you will also put afditional pressure on the GC.

edit2:

And most important, actors are not threads! So even if you create 1M actors, they will only run on as many threads as the pool has. So depending on the throughput setting in the config every actor will process n messages before the thread gets released to the pool again.

Note that blocking a thread (includes sleeping) will NOT return it to the pool!

Comment: Yes, routers are a good choice in many cases, but I don't think that they work in this situation. I detailed my question to explain why.

Comment: @drexin, can you elaborate a bit on why the top level actor error kernel is more expensive than child actor, and hows the child actor is (way) cheaper? As far as I understand, the error kernel is just a pattern that pushes error prone task to context actor.

Answer (score 8):

An actor which will receive one message right after its creation and die right after sending the result can be replaced by a future. Futures are more lightweight than actors.

You can use `pipeTo` to receive the future result when its done. For instance in your actor launching the computations:

```
def receive = {
  case t: Task => future { executeTask( t ) }.pipeTo(self)
  case r: Result => processTheResult(r)
}
```

where `executeTask` is your function taking a `Task` to return a `Result`.

However, I would reuse actors from a pool through a router as explained in @drexin answer.

Comment: The workers communicate with other actors in the system. They don't just run some isolated code

Comment: I detailed my problem a little bit. Using futures only is not a solution for me.

Comment: I've read your edit and I don't see any problems with futures. You can define a maximum number of futures running at the same time by defining a custom `ExecutionContext`. Using the monadic operators, you can compose several futures together (such as futures to other service results) and pass a state along.

Comment: That might be. I didn't want to detail further but workers are schedule based on some logic that involves their current state. Although your solution is possible it is certainly cleaner and more maintainable to abstract the running tasks in stand-alone worker actors.

Comment: If task processing higly complex, its cost may largely dominate the cost of actor creation... The only way to answer the question is then to benchmark it using the processing workflow that you want to put in production.

Comment: Careful with futures! It's not a panacea! There is a fixed number of resources available to execute them and unbounded creation of them can wreak havoc!

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with 10000 remote actors created from some `main` context by a `root` actor, same scheme as in prod module a single actor was created. MBP 2.5GHz x2:

- in main: main ? root // main asks root to create an actor
- in main: actorOf(child) // create a child
- in root: watch(child) // watch lifecycle messages
- in root: root ? child // wait for response (connection check)
- in child: child ! root // response (connection ok)
- in root: root ! main // notify created

Code:

```
def start(userName: String) = {
  logger.error("HELLOOOOOOOO ")
  val n: Int = 10000
  var t0, t1: Long = 0
  t0 = System.nanoTime
  for (i <- 0 to n) {
    val msg = StartClient(userName + i)
    Await.result(rootActor ? msg, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ClientStarted] match {
    case succ @ ClientStarted(userName) => 
      // logger.info("[C][SUCC] Client started: " + succ)
    case _ => 
      logger.error("Terminated on waiting for response from " + i + "-th actor")
      throw new RuntimeException("[C][FAIL] Could not start client: " + msg)
    }
  }
  t1 = System.nanoTime
  logger.error("Starting of a single actor of " + n + ": " + ((t1 - t0) / 1000000.0 / n.toDouble) + " ms")
}
```

The result:

```
Starting of a single actor of 10000: 0.3642917 ms
```

There was a message stating that "Slf4jEventHandler started" between "HELOOOOOOOO" and "Starting of a single", so the experiment seems even more realistic (?)

Dispatchers was a default (a PinnedDispatcher starting a new thread each and every time), and it seemed like all that stuff is the same as `Thread.start()` was, for a long long time since Java 1 - 500K-1M cycles or so ^)

That's why I've changed all code inside loop, to a `new java.lang.Thread().start()`

The result:

```
Starting of a single actor of 10000: 0.1355219 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Actors make great finite state machines so let that help drive your design here. If your request handling state is greatly simplified by having one actor per request then do that. I find that actors are particularly good at managing more than two states as a rule of thumb.

Commonly though, one request handling actor that references request state from within a collection that it maintains as part of its own state is a common approach. Note that this can also be achieved with an Akka reactive stream and the use of the scan stage.